# jQuery lightGallery toggle thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightgallery

Very impressed with jQuery lightGallery, it's been a joy to use. As per the first example on the lightGallery website, Gallery with animated thumbnails (http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/examples.html) I have moved navigation arrows to the sides but have left the thumbnails hidden.

```
#lg-gallery .thumb-cont .thumb-info {
    display: none;
}
#lg-action {
    position: static;
}
#lg-action a#lg-prev,
#lg-action a#lg-next {
    margin-top: -14px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 9999999;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#lg-action a#lg-prev {
    left: 18px;
}
#lg-action a#lg-next {
    right: 18px;
}
```

I have moved the open thumbs button next to the gallery close button at the top right hand corner of the window, as follows.

```
#lg-action a.cl-thumb {
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    right: 50px;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

So, how do I hook-up an open/close toggle for the thumbs using the thumbs button? I guess I need to look at the onOpen callback, but I'm not sure how to use it, something like this perhaps.

```
onOpen: function() {
    $("#lg-action a.cl-thumb").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#lg-gallery").hasClass("open")) {
            $("#lg-gallery .thumb-cont").slideDown();
            $("#lg-gallery").removeClass('open');
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

This (obviously) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding a function to the onOpen callback. I added a class called 'open-toggle' (and set the required css) to #lg-gallery.open when the thumbs button is first clicked. The second click removes the 'open-toggle' and 'open' classes from #lg-gallery and re-sets the css.

```
onOpen: function() {
    $("#lg-action a.cl-thumb").on("click", function() {
        $gallery = $("#lg-gallery");
        if ($gallery.hasClass("open-toggle")) {
            $gallery.removeClass('open-toggle open');
            $("#lg-gallery .lg-slide").css("padding-bottom", "0");  
        }
        else {
            $gallery.addClass("open-toggle");
            $("#lg-gallery.open .lg-slide").css("padding-bottom", "120px");
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

I found that the images don't get out of the way if you toggle the thumbs bar, but they do get out of the way for the example on the website. I opened up Firebug and found that the website example page has a file called base.css which contains the following line:

```
* { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

I added this line to my css and animated the padding-bottom so that the images didn't jump to size when the thumbs were toggled.

```
onOpen: function() {
    $("#lg-action a.cl-thumb").on("click", function() {
        $gallery = $("#lg-gallery");
        if ($gallery.hasClass("open-toggle")) {
            $("#lg-gallery .lg-slide").animate({ 
                "padding-bottom": 0 
            }, 500);    
            $gallery.removeClass('open-toggle open');
        }
        else {
            $("#lg-gallery.open .lg-slide").animate({ 
                "padding-bottom": 120 
            }, 500);
            $gallery.addClass("open-toggle");
        }
    });
}
```

Anyway, maybe this will point someone in the right direction.